# Pass a value from a function to array value in another function

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a function:

```
def latest_file_to_backup():
   # returns latest file from a directory
   # called variable $latest_file
```

I have another function which I'm attempting to make which performs an API call to upload a file:

```
def auth_to_pcloud(latest_file):
   from pcloud import PyCloud
   # auth details here - properly working
   #pc.uploadfile(files=['/home/pi/<<USE:$latest_file here>>'], path='/a/remote/path/here')
```

I cannot figure out an easy way to pass the value of `$latest_file` to the `auth_to_pcloud()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an f-string:

```py
def latest_file_to_backup():
   # returns latest file from a directory
   # called variable $latest_file

def auth_to_pcloud(latest_file):
   from pcloud import PyCloud
   # auth details here - properly working
   pc.uploadfile(files=[f'/home/pi/{latest_file}'], path='/a/remote/path/here')

latest_file = latest_file_to_backup()
auth_to_pcloud(latest_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try the easy way?
Take the value from the first method into a variable and pass it on to the upload method.

```
latest_file = latest_file_to_backup()
auth_to_pcloud(latest_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would be an answer to your problem:

1. return your file as binary
2. write binary data into a temp file
3. pass the temp file to second function

```
def latest_file_to_backup():
    #codes 
    return b'file'  # Replace your file in binary format
    

def auth_to_pcloud(file):
    # Your code 

# generate binary data to pass as argument
binary_data = latest_file_to_backup()

# Create a temporary file and write the binary data
with open("temp_file.bin", "wb") as temp_file:
    temp_file.write(binary_data)

# Pass the file to the second function
auth_to_pcloud("temp_file.bin")
```